# ssh multiple users key and password

Tags: permissions, ssh, login, password

I have set up my sshd to require both the key and a password from a ssh client, this works fine for my main root account.

I tried to make a separate account that does not have root access, the key from the external client is in the /home/<nonrootuser>/.ssh/authorized_keys file but i still get a pubkey denied if I try to ssh <nonrootuser>@server.

If I disable the key authentication everything works as it should, I can login with a password. If I disable password authentication, my root account logs in and my non root account gets asked for a password.

My sshd_config includes:

```
AuthenticationMethods "publickey,password"
#PasswordAuthentication yes commented out
#PubkeyAuthentication yes commented out

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes

AllowUsers <rootuser> <nonrootuser>
```

Can I force both accounts to do both password and key authentication?

Comment: First step is to check that the ownership and permissions of the authorized_keys file and its parent directories are not too permissive. Next, run your ssh command with verbosity `ssh -v` or `ssh -vv` or `ssh -vvv`) to get further information about why it's failing.

Comment: @steeldriver my permissions for the .ssh file in the nonroot account were indeed wrong, I changed them and now everything works, thanks a lot!